# How to use a thin jar instead of a fat jar?

Tags: java, apache-flink, uberjar

We're currently deploying our Flink applications as a fat-jar using the maven-shade-plugin. Problem is, each application jar ends up being approximately 130-140 MB which is a pain to build and deploy every time. Is there a way to exclude dependencies and just deploy a thin jar to the cluster which comes up to about 50 kB?

Comment: Yes, just don't have any dependencies (except for the flink core dependencies) then your fat-jar will be smaller. If you have required dependencies, you need to include them. How else would they end up in flink container?

Answer (score 3):

You can place the dependency JARs in the cluster beforehand in Flink's `lib` (see [Avoid Dynamic  Classloading](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#avoiding-dynamic-classloading)) and just upload the thin JAR on each job submission.

Comment: Can I remove all of my classes from the fat jar files, then put it into the lib directory, and start Flink with my thin jar files?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we do it with Gradle!

We have two sub-projects:

- `job`: For the *stream job* that we want to run
- `runtime`: For *additional* runtime dependencies (e.g. a custom `FileSystem` implementation)

We create a new *gradle configuration* for dependencies that are *provided* at runtime:

```
configurations {
  provided,
  compile.extendsFrom provided
}
```

and then mark the *provided* dependencies as:

```
provided("org.apache.flink:flink-java:1.6.0")  // flink java v1.6.0
```

Then, we modify the `jar` task to build a jar *without any `provided` dependencies*:

```
jar {
  dependsOn configurations.runtime
  from {
    (configurations.runtime - configurations.provided).collect {
      it.isDirectory()? it : zipTree(it)
    }
  } {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
  }
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.Entrypoint'
  }
}
```

The result is a `jar` with *required* dependencies (`compile`) bundled which we then deploy using the Web UI.

As for the *custom runtime* dependencies, we build a custom Docker image and push the built artifact (`runtime.jar`, built using same configuration as above) to the `libs/`directory in Flink. You can do that manually too if you are not using Docker.

And, lastly, in our particular case there is *no direct dependency* defined between our job and the runtime dependency (which is discovered using reflection).